Файлы html вне видимости проекта на java
https://github.com/karlsonkiller/Crud_project3
Тут загружен мой Crud проект, для обучения. Я не могу понять, почему у меня выдает ошибку при запуске TomCat, не удается открыть файл index.html.
В проекте используется Spring, Hibernate, Mysql, Maven, Tomcat
AppConfig, AppInit, WebConfig - конфигурационные классы для Spring
resources - папка в которой хранятся настройки для Hibernate, а так же Mysql
UserController - это класс, который управляет, страницами на сервере ( открывает и перенаправляет на другие html формы )
webapp - папка, в которой хранятся html файлы
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/pages/index.html]

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/pages/index.html]")

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/pages/index.html]")


Помимо ссылки на гитхаб, добавьте в вопрос основные классы приложения и конфигурационные файлы.

сейчас сделаю, не подумал

сделал комментарии к проекту

Насколько я знаю, thymeleaf, а Вы его используете, ищет шаблоны страниц в папке templates. Создайте эту папку в ресурсах и перенесите в нее файл index.html.

Это правда, но, насколько я видел на Гитхабе, автор явно указывал пути для Thymeleaf, да и тем более у него не Spring Boot, а простой Spring. Так что странно, что этот ответ помог решить проблему, хотя, может, я что-то не понимаю
